# Find angle between anchored node and current position of camera in arcore

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I want to show, say andy once arcore tracking started and plan is discovered. After I anchored the node somewhere nearby and then i move away from andy.

I have an arrow at the bottom of the screen I want to rotate/point the arrow as i move away my camera such that the arrow always point to the anchored node.

I have done remaining thing but not able to find the angle to which i need to keep rotating the arrow image so that it always point towards anchored node.

I am using sceneform framework, arcore sdk in android studio.

Comment: Could you clarify? Maybe some simple drawings so I can help you, right now I quite didn't get what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: let say you are seeing a 3d cat at your table via mobile ar camera, now you turn around and looking at some thing else let say your TV. I need to put an arrow at the bottom of screen (which I have) and point always at the 3d cat at which your were looking before turning away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the code I used to achieve what was intended :

```
 Vector3 cameraPosition = arSceneView.getScene().getCamera().getWorldPosition();
 Vector3 catPosition = catNode.getWorldPosition();
 Vector3 direction = Vector3.subtract(cameraPosition, catPosition);
 Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.lookRotation(direction, Vector3.up());
 catNode.setWorldRotation(lookRotation);
```

Comment: Good that you find the way :) I'm not sure though if world position everywhere is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

So based on your comments you have to do couple of things, I will break it apart for you:
1. Track position of the cat (Point A)
2. Track position of the camera (device) - this should be accessible from ARCore API. (Point B)
3. Now you have to get the direction, given two points A, B mentioned previously when you subtract A from B you get direction vector (can be normalized for simplification later and even you can reduce it to just 2d vector not 3d). Imagine this to yourself in 2d if having problems in 3d.
4. This part is your choice, you can compute angle difference or compare rotation and decide how your arrow/pointer to cat will look like. Left/right pointer or something in a compass style, choice is yours.

Comment: Yeah i know the logical approach to the question, I was looking for classes or methods. Thanks though